# PLAYWRIGHT testing - How to skip to the next action if a click on a button is not possible (is not present)?

Tags: javascript, typescript, testing, automated-tests, playwright

as anticipated in the question, I'd like to know if is possible to attempt a click action on a button, but if it's not in the page then the test skip that action (without being stucked or throwing an error) and continue to the next one.
To be more specific, I have a modal where I can add rows to a table, but what I'd like to do is to add a new row only if a given button in the modal is not present, while if it's present the action would be to press first on that button and then proceeding to add a new row.

I ask you if it's possible because I'd like to avoid conditional statements during the test. Just let me know, thank you in advance :)

Comment: Accepted answer is outdated, see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/77288539

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check if the element is present then do something if not then do nothing or something else.

```js
 const modal = page.locator('modal-selector');
    
 if (await modal.isVisible()) {
   // do thing
 } else {
   // do another thing
 }
```

Comment: But I don't need to close the modal. I need to check if a given button is present in the modal and if not, I keep the modal opened and proceed to add a new row to the table inside the modal. Also, I wondered if it was possible to avoid if statements.

Comment: Oh, I see. I've updated the answer. So, you don't the `closeModal` method, but everything in it is suitable for your case. No, you can't avoid if statement, you can replace it with a ternary operator but I don't think that would be a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const locator = page.locator("some selector");
if (locator.count() > 0) {
  // found locator, do something
} else {
  // not found, do something else
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 

Comment: you missing `await` before `locator.count()`.

Answer (score 0):

### From v1.33 you may use [OR](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locator#locator-or) condition natively for this scenario

```
await expect(locatorA.or(locatorB)).toBeVisible()
```

**Simple Example:**

Consider a scenario where you'd like to click on a "New email" button, but sometimes a security settings dialog shows up instead. In this case, you can wait for either a "New email" button, or a dialog and act accordingly.

```
const newEmail = page.getByRole('button', { name: 'New' });
const dialog = page.getByText('Confirm security settings');
await expect(newEmail.or(dialog)).toBeVisible();
if (await dialog.isVisible())
  await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Dismiss' }).click();
await newEmail.click();
```

Reference: [How to wait for multiple selectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70675571/how-to-wait-for-multiple-selectors/77288539#77288539)