# How to wait for multiple selectors?

Tags: playwright

For example, I'm testing a search page, which will show the result numbers in `.text > span:nth-child(1)`.

However, if not any result, it will only show `text="nothing"` or `.text > span:nth-child(1)` is not exist.

So how can I wait for both conditions?

Comment: You mean, to wait for either `text="nothing"` or `.text > span:nth-child(1)`. So exclusive?

Comment: @ChristianBaumann, yes, only one condition will happen.

Comment: Accepted answer is outdated .Use this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/77288539

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to use a comma-separated list of CSS selectors which will match all elements that can be selected by one of the selectors in that list:

```js
//                                           ↓ comma
await page.locator('.text > span:nth-child(1), span:has-text("nothing")').innerText();
```

It will wait for either `.text > span:nth-child(1)` or `span:has-text("nothing")`.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like much more graceful!

Comment: With this solution, you don't know which of the elements has been found.

Comment: @ChristianBaumann, it could be figure out by `innerText` found. if text is "nothing", the second element found. In more complex situation, check handler returned by `locator` will be enough in most cases.

Comment: And if using XPath notation, use a vertical bar instead of a comma.

Comment: Looks like this cannot be used in combination with test ID right?

Answer (score 4):

#### Never rely on pure [CSS selectors](https://playwright.dev/docs/other-locators#css-locator) as per playwright docs.

#### From v1.33 you may use [OR](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locator#locator-or) condition natively

```
await expect(locatorA.or(locatorB)).toBeVisible()
```

**Simple Example:**

Consider a scenario where you'd like to click on a "New email" button, but sometimes a security settings dialog shows up instead. In this case, you can wait for either a "New email" button, or a dialog and act accordingly.

```
const newEmail = page.getByRole('button', { name: 'New' });
const dialog = page.getByText('Confirm security settings');
await expect(newEmail.or(dialog)).toBeVisible();
if (await dialog.isVisible())
  await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Dismiss' }).click();
await newEmail.click();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can wait for both elements, using a try-catch, and setting a boolean variable, depending on which element is being found.

In Java you could use something like

```
Boolean nothingFound, resultsFound = false;

try {
    page.waitForSelector("text=\"nothing\"");
    nothingFound = true;

} catch (Exception e) {}

try {
    page.waitForSelector(".text > span:nth-child(1)");
    resultsFound = true;
} catch (Exception e) {}
```

I'm not a Javascript expert, but I think something like this should work:

```
let  nothingFound, resultsFound = false;

try {
    await page.waitForSelector('text="nothing"');
    nothingFound = true;
}
catch (e) {}

try {
    await page.waitForSelector('.text > span:nth-child(1)');
    resultsFound = true;
}
catch (e) {}
```

Comment: Thanks, this answer can be used when different action will be take depends on element find, but may wait for too much timeout.

Comment: Never catch error like this , basically you are suppressing errors.

Comment: Instead assert the state after the action.

Answer (score 0):

In case you need a solution for waiting for either of two test IDs, this is the only solution I am aware of:

```js
/* Note that the `.then` is needed because
 * `waitFor` returns `Promise<void>` and we
 * can't distinguish which `void` in `element`
 * is which `Promise` instance
 */

const element1Promise = page
  .getByTestId('testId1')
  .waitFor()
  .then(() => 'element1');
const element2Promise = page
  .getByTestId('testId2')
  .waitFor()
  .then(() => 'element2');

// Wait for either of the promises to settle
const element = await Promise.race([
  element1Promise,
  element2Promise,
]);

// Use `element` for conditional logic
```