# Conditionally wait for locators in Playwright

Tags: javascript, typescript, playwright

I have a sign-in form I am testing using Playwright that has one of two possible states:

1. If the user already exists, it will only ask for their password and present a "Sign In" button.
2. If it is a new user, it will ask for their "First & last name" and password and present a "Save" button.

Due to some logic of our authentication system, it's not practical for it to be entirely deterministic so I need to ensure my test handles each of those cases successfully.

One such solution is [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71374820/6090140):

```
if (await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Sign In' }).count() > 0) {
  await page.getByLabel('Password').fill('password');
  await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Sign In' }).click();
} else {
  await page.getByLabel('First & last name').fill('Bob Alice');
  await page.getByLabel('Password').fill('password');
  await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Save' }).click();
}
```

However, this requires the page to wait for my timeout before continuing.  I could reduce the timeout for the conditional check [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67922197/6090140), but this adds more brittleness to the test.

How can I use conditional logic without forced timeouts to ensure one of two code paths in Playwright is executed?

Comment: See this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/77288539

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `Promise.race`, you can wait for one of many possible locators to be visible, then return details about which locator succeeded.  Here's such a helper function in Typescript:

```
import { Locator } from '@playwright/test';

type WaitForRes = [ locatorIndex: number, locator: Locator ];

export async function waitForOneOf(
  locators: Locator[],
): Promise<WaitForRes> {
  const res = await Promise.race([
    ...locators.map(async (locator, index): Promise<WaitForRes> => {
      let timedOut = false;
      await locator.waitFor({ state: 'visible' }).catch(() => timedOut = true);
      return [ timedOut ? -1 : index, locator ];
    }),
  ]);
  if (res[0] === -1) {
    throw new Error('no locator visible before timeout');
  }
  return res;
}
```

And here is how it can be used to solve the problem:

```
const [ index ] = await waitForOneOf([
  page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Sign In' }),
  page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Save' }),
]);
const isExistingAccount = index === 0;
if (isExistingAccount) {
  await page.getByLabel('Password').fill('password');
  await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Sign In' }).click();
} else {
  await page.getByLabel('First & last name').fill('Bob Alice');
  await page.getByLabel('Password').fill('password');
  await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Save' }).click();
}
```

The `waitForOneOf` wrapper gives some benefits over simply using `Promise.race` [[1]](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/11853#issuecomment-1030262014):

1. The expectation is that all but one of the locators is going to time out and throw an error.  This isn't an issue because the `Promise.race` will discard those rejections; however, if you are debugging within VS Code (or elsewhere), this thrown error will trigger a breakpoint that pauses the code execution.  To mitigate this, we `.catch` the error instead.
2. By catching the error, we can also specify its failure and if no locator resolves correctly (`if (res[0] === -1)`), then we can still throw an error.
3. By returning the resolved locator and its index, we can have conditional code execution, as demonstrated above.

Answer (score 3):

This is the simplest way I've found to determine state based on which locator shows up:

```js
const accountExists = await Promise.any([
    page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Sign In' }).waitFor().then(() => false),
    page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Save' }).waitFor().then(() => true),
]).catch(() => {
    throw "Missing button";
});
```

Then you can use it however you need:

```js
if (accountExists) {
    await page.getByLabel('Password').fill('password');
    await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Sign In' }).click();
} else {
    await page.getByLabel('Name').fill('Alice');
    await page.getByLabel('Password').fill('password');
    await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Save' }).click();
}
```