# TypeScript eslint no-uncessary-condition when chaning a variable with catch

Tags: typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

I'm running into a [@typescript-link no-unnecessary-condition warning](https://%20%20https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-unnecessary-condition/) with the following code ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74403846)):

```
async function waitForOneOf(locators: Locator[]): Promise<WaitForRes> {
  // timeToWait can be long because if it fails, the whole test fails anyway.
  const timeToWait = 5000;
  const res = await Promise.race([
    ...locators.map(async (locator, index): Promise<WaitForRes> => {
      let timedOut = false;
      await locator
        .waitFor({ state: 'visible', timeout: timeToWait })
        .catch(() => {
          timedOut = true;
        });
      return [timedOut ? -1 : index, locator];
    }),
  ]);
  if (res[0] === -1) {
    throw new Error(`no locator visible before timeout ${locators.toString()}`);
  }
  return res;
}
```

The problem is the line

return [timedOut ? -1 : index, locator];

Eslint identifies `timedOut` is always falsy because `let timedOut = false`.  However, I think this is incorrect (it is not always falsy) becaue the value of `timedOut` may be changed in the catch function because it is an arrow function, so the `timedOut` variable is accessible to it.

Is my understand correct-- this eslint error is incorrect?  Or am I misunderstanding how variables work in JS/TS in this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to this [famous issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998).

`timedOut` is incorrectly inferred as `false`.

You can fix it with a type assertion : `let timedOut = false as boolean;`

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can define type of timedOut

`let timedOut: true | false = false;`

and type would be inferred correct.

Comment: No, see https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler strange thing. I believe that you're right, but my lint doesn't show any error if I define let timedOut: true | false = false; , for example.

(I don't prefer type casting via as)