Playwright: Is there a way to use multiple locators for the same element?
switching from Selenium Webdriver and have a Locator question.
We have a situation where our devs use different locators in different places for the same element.
We use an "array" or locators, like this:
loading = "div.spinner img[src*=load], .table-spinner-background>div, [alt=Loading], [class*='spinner-border']," \
              " [data-ui-handle='circle-spinner'], div.sps-circle, [data-ui-handle='circle-spinner'], .c-spinner"

Is there a way to do the same in Playwright?

Did you try it? It should work out of the box. This is just standard CSS syntax, which works perfectly well in Playwright. Playwright also offer the .or() function to provide logical 'or's between locators. That said, I'd avoid doing this 99% of the time. Generally, you want to pick one thing or multiple items of the exact same type (class, element, test id, role, etc). If you're using this pattern all over the place, tests will be unmaintainable.

Does this answer your question? How can I use page.waitForSelector in Playwright for one of two selectors?

See this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/77288539/1831456
