How to find an element by using Or in the locator?
I have 2 very similar elements one different pages that I need to test:
<input name="myName">
<input name="name">

In my code I tried to find the input element using Or (||) keyword, but that did Not work.
Can this be done without xpath, only by using CSS expression?
this._nameInput = page.locator(
    'input[name="name"]' || 'input[name*="Name"]'
)


This question is similar to: How can I use page.waitForSelector in Playwright for one of two selectors?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

See this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/77288539/1831456

You can use the or method:
lowercase = page.locator('input[name="name"]')
wildcard = page.locator('input[name*="Name"]');
this._nameInput = lowercase.or(wildcard);


CSS only would be to use a comma separator:
this._nameInput = page.locator('input[name="name"],input[name*="Name"]')

